# How to pass a variable number of props to a JSX tag in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to create a website which has many "showcase" pages. On each of them i have a variable number of images (not always the same amount) and im using props to pass images to each page in their respective JSX tags as shown below. But i don't want to have: const {title, image1, image2, image3, etc} = props

Is there a way that i can use a single image prop and in my JSX tag use it as many times for any number of images?

The code below is what i would ike to achieve but of course it doesn't work.

Hockey.js

```
class Sport extends Component { 
  render() {
   return ( 
    <div> 
       <Pages title="Hockey" image={hockey1, hockey2, hockey3}/>
       <Pages title="Football" image={foot1, foot2}/>

    </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Pages.js

```
const Pages = props => {
    const { title, image } = props
    return ( <div></div>)
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use an array of images as a prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to pass a list of images;

```js
class Sport extends Component { 
  render() {
   return ( 
    <div> 
       <Pages title="Hockey" images={[hockey1, hockey2, hockey3]} />
       <Pages title="Football" images={[foot1, foot2]} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then use in your component:

```js
const  Pages = props => {
  const {title, images} = props;

  return (<div class="pages">
    {images.map((image, index) => (
      <div class="page" key={index}>
        <img src={image} />
      </div>
    )}
   </div>);
}
```

Comment: that sounds so obvious can't beleive i didn't think of that. Thanks man. will try it now.

Comment: Update the answer with example.

Comment: It works but now i have: <img src={props.images[0]} alt=""/>
     <img src={props.images[1]} alt=""/>
     <img src={props.images[2]} alt=""/>
and if i have a page with only 2 or 4 images then what do i do?

Comment: See example. Use loops.

Comment: Pay attention that `<Pages title="Football" images={[foot1, foot2]} />` will create a new array on each render! that means that Pages will **re-render** each time `Sport` renders